# What is the replacement for Xamarin.Auth within .NET 7.0 MAUI?

Tags: .net, maui

What libraries within the .NET 7 MAIU framework replace the Xamarin.Auth?

I just want users of my Android and iOS app to be able to sign in with either their Apple or Google account.

```
     private async Task OnGoogleSignInButtonClicked()
        {
            // Google Sign-In logic here
            try
            {
                // Create an OAuth2Authenticator for Google Sign-In
                var authenticator = new OAuth2Authenticator(
                    clientId: "YOUR_GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID",
                    scope: "email", // Add additional scopes as needed
                    authorizeUrl: new Uri("https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth"),
                    redirectUrl: new Uri("YOUR_REDIRECT_URL"),
                    isUsingNativeUI: true);

                // Subscribe to the Completed event to handle the authentication result
                authenticator.Completed += OnGoogleAuthenticationCompleted;

                // Present the Google Sign-In UI to the user
                var presenter = new Xamarin.Auth.Presenters.OAuthLoginPresenter();
                presenter.Login(authenticator);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // Handle any exceptions
            }
        }

        private async Task OnAppleSignInButtonClicked()
        {
            // Apple Sign-In logic here
            try
            {
                // Use AppleSignInAuthenticator to initiate Apple Sign-In
                var appleResult = await AppleSignInAuthenticator.SignInAsync();
                if (appleResult.Status == AppleSignInAuthenticatorStatus.Completed)
                {
                    // Access the user's account information using appleResult.Account
                    var user = appleResult.Account;

                    // Handle successful sign-in
                    // Redirect the user to the main app page or perform further actions
                }
                else
                {
                    // Handle failed sign-in
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // Handle any exceptions
            }
        }

        // Event handler for Google Sign-In completion
        private async void OnGoogleAuthenticationCompleted(object sender, AuthenticatorCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                // Access the user's account information using e.Account
                var user = await GetGoogleUserInfoAsync(e.Account);

                // Handle successful sign-in
                // Redirect the user to the main app page or perform further actions
            }
            else
            {
                // Handle failed sign-in
            }
        }

        // Helper method to fetch Google user info
        private async Task<GoogleUserInfo> GetGoogleUserInfoAsync(Account account)
        {
            var request = new OAuth2Request("GET", new Uri("https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v2/userinfo"), null, account);
            var response = await request.GetResponseAsync();
            if (response != null && response.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                var json = response.GetResponseText();
                return Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<GoogleUserInfo>(json);
            }
            return null;
        }
    }

    // Helper class for storing Google user info
    public class GoogleUserInfo
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        // Add more properties as needed for Google user info
    }
```

I've looked at the WebAuthenticator, but they keep referencing some sort of "app associated" web-based backend connector. However, I just want a strict "client app" that uses Apple and Google identity providers.

Comment: if I remember correctly you would use the [IWebAuthenticator interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/platform-integration/communication/authentication?tabs=android) for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now, MAUI only has the Web Authenticator. This interface lets you start browser-based authentication flows, which listen for a callback to a specific URL registered to the app.

Here is the example for [Apple Sign in](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/platform-integration/communication/authentication?tabs=android#apple-sign-in):

```
var scheme = "..."; // Apple, Microsoft, Google, Facebook, etc.
var authUrlRoot = "https://";
WebAuthenticatorResult result = null;

if (scheme.Equals("Apple")
    && DeviceInfo.Platform == DevicePlatform.iOS
    && DeviceInfo.Version.Major >= 13)
{
    // Use Native Apple Sign In API's
    result = await AppleSignInAuthenticator.AuthenticateAsync();
}
else
{
    // Web Authentication flow
    var authUrl = new Uri($"{authUrlRoot}{scheme}");
    var callbackUrl = new Uri("myapp://");

    result = await WebAuthenticator.Default.AuthenticateAsync(authUrl, callbackUrl);
}

var authToken = string.Empty;

if (result.Properties.TryGetValue("name", out string name) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(name))
    authToken += $"Name: {name}{Environment.NewLine}";

if (result.Properties.TryGetValue("email", out string email) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(email))
    authToken += $"Email: {email}{Environment.NewLine}";

// Note that Apple Sign In has an IdToken and not an AccessToken
authToken += result?.AccessToken ?? result?.IdToken;
```